# Siri Intent Donation for Shortcuts ending up with error

Tags: ios, siri, sirikit, ios12, sirishortcuts

I have created a simple intent for Siri shortcut and whenever i am trying to donate the intent, it is ending up with following error.

> Interaction donation failed: %@ Error Domain=IntentsErrorDomain
>   Code=1901 "Cannot donate interaction  {
>       intent =  {
>           user = ;
>           identifier = 06DE1A38-6D46-4CB8-B825-3788E6A81420;
>       };
>       dateInterval = <_NSConcreteDateInterval: 0x60000043cce0> (Start Date) 2018-07-17 12:38:39 +0000 + (Duration) 0.000000 seconds = (End
>   Date) 2018-07-17 12:38:39 +0000;
>       intentResponse = ;
>       groupIdentifier = ;
>       intentHandlingStatus = Unspecified;
>       identifier = F145FA84-7147-41A8-8698-681F06C8CEB5;
>       direction = Unspecified; } with intent that has no valid shortcut types" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot donate interaction
>    {
>       intent =  {
>           user = ;
>           identifier = 06DE1A38-6D46-4CB8-B825-3788E6A81420;
>       };
>       dateInterval = <_NSConcreteDateInterval: 0x60000043cce0> (Start Date) 2018-07-17 12:38:39 +0000 + (Duration) 0.000000 seconds = (End
>   Date) 2018-07-17 12:38:39 +0000;
>       intentResponse = ;
>       groupIdentifier = ;
>       intentHandlingStatus = Unspecified;
>       identifier = F145FA84-7147-41A8-8698-681F06C8CEB5;
>       direction = Unspecified; } with intent that has no valid shortcut types}

The following is my intent donation code

```
func donateInteraction() {
        let intent = GetBalanceIntent()
        intent.suggestedInvocationPhrase = "Get Balance"
        let interaction = INInteraction(intent: intent, response: nil)
        interaction.donate { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                if let error = error as NSError? {
                    print("Interaction donation failed: %@", error)
                } else {
                    print("Successfully donated interaction")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show me your `.intentdefinition` file? A print will be enough

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I missed initializing the custom property(i.e user in the above example) which i have defined in the definition file.

Adding it solved the problem. Code looks like this:

```
func donateInteraction() {
        let intent = GetBalanceIntent()
        intent.suggestedInvocationPhrase = "Get Balance"
        intent.user = "vittal"
        let interaction = INInteraction(intent: intent, response: nil)
        interaction.donate { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                if let error = error as NSError? {
                    print("Interaction donation failed: %@", error)
                } else {
                    print("Successfully donated interaction")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You really have to add all properties, even enums that are not optional (and I thought would have a default value)

Answer (score 3):

[image]

I had the same problem, I realized that my INIntent subclass name on my swift file wasn't matching the one in the . intentdefinition, hope this helps someone.

Comment: Hey, were you able to successfully run multiple intents?

Answer (score 1):

Your intent definition file should have valid shortcut types. You can add those under shortcut types.